# Is there a name for "mimetype patterns"?

Tags: mime-types

Is there a name for the "mimetype patterns" that can be specified, for example, in an HTTP `Accept` header?

For example, I'm writing a function which will return a file encoded as a specific mimetype:

```
def get_encoded_file(original, mimetype):
    ... magic ...
```

But the `mimetype` can actually be a "mimetype pattern" like `image/*`… So calling it a "mimetype" seems wrong.

So, is there a formal name for "mimetype patterns" like, ex, `image/*`, or `text/*`?

Comment: D'oh! Obviously. Can you answer the question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is official, but "mime type wildcards" seems to be used.